# 3D Scatter Plot Matlab with Connected Points

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to connect points in a 3d scatter plot in Matlab that have the same Z value.

```
num=1e2;
x=rand(num,1);
y=rand(num,1);
z=zeros(num,1);
z(randsample(num,.25*num),:)=1;
scatter3(x,y,z);hold on;scatter3(x1,y1,z1);hold on;
%connect dots with same Z value, so there should be horizontal line between points in the same Z plane
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "connect points", but here's a direction:

```
figure, hold on
for u = unique(z(:))'
    plot3(x(z == u), y(z == u), z(z == u))
end
view(-37.5, 30)
```

Alternatively, perhaps you can modify your data and use the [`contour3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html) command instead.

Comment: In my data points with the same data z value are linked and I want to show those links point to point but not link all points. I tried contour but not sure if I am implementing it correcty, but I don't think it will do the trick.

Comment: @diplodocuscoffeespot Try now, I'm not sure what you have in mind. An example plot would be helpful.

Comment: Here is what my data looks like, the line plot is linking lines but not only those with the same Z. Sorry I am being terse, I am at work and finding it hard to get the full story across. http://i.imgur.com/9mlOHsU.jpg

Comment: Thanks! After contour not working I tried this without having read your comment. Good to see external validation for my method.